# How do damage increases and redirects interact?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

I ran into a weird situation today. I was playing Absolute Zero on Insula Primalis. **Two** obsidian fields were drawn:

> ### Obsidian Field
>
> Increase all Damage dealt by 1. At the end of their turn, 1 player may discard 2 cards to destroy this card.

I had the Isothermic Transducer in play.

> ### Isothermic Transducer
>
> When Absolute Zero is dealt Fire Damage, Absolute Zero deals 1 Target that much Cold Damage.

Now my power is to deal either cold or fire damage to myself. So how do these two interact? It seems like one of two different things should happen:

1. I deal myself **1 + 2 == 3** fire damage, and then deal 1 target **3** cold damage. This is what I ended up doing. Or
2. I I deal myself **1 + 2 == 3** fire damage, and then deal 1 target **3 + 2 == 5** cold damage.

**2** is what I would like to do, but this seems kind of cheaty. Is this really how these two cards interact?

Comment: From the way it's worded, something is dealing damage to AZ, and AZ is dealing damage to something else. These are both instances of something dealing damage, and thus both subject to being increased by OF. This is a comment because I have absolutely no knowledge of this game, and perhaps there's a rule or FAQ out there that says otherwise. But, this is how it would work in M:TG (both instances of "deals damage" would be modified by the replacement effect as they are separate events), and this is usually a good guide because M:TG formalized a lot of board game concepts.

Comment: @ikegami in the case of SotM there are some places where a MtG background actually makes it harder to intuit the SotM behavior because of how they work differently. (The big ones are that mass damage in SotM isn't simultaneous, damage triggers can and do interrupt the resolution and removing the source of an effect can halt the effect mid-resolution).  But none of those apply here, and everything in this case works basically the way it would in Magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Isothermic Transducer is not a redirect

Isothermic Tranducer is a triggered effect that deals damage.  Like any other instance of damage, it will be boosted +2 by the two Obsidian Fields.

The amount of damage that Absolute Zero (AZ) deals is calculated from the amount of damage AZ takes - that is, the amount of life he lost.  The initial number stated by the ability dealing damage before increases and decreases doesn't matter, only the final number.

So if AZ tries to deal himself 1 Fire damage, it will be boosted +2 and he will take 3 Fire damage.  Then Isothermic Transducer will react and he will deal 3 damage +2 and deal 5 cold damage to the target of his choice.

(If he choose to deal that damage to himself and he has his Null-point Calibration Unit in play, he will heal 5 hp)

---

There *are* true redirects in the game, such as Visionary's Decoy Projection, Baron Blade's Elemental Redistributor, and Legacy's Lead from the Front.  For a redirection effect, once you have determined who the damage is finally pointing at, recalculate the damage increases and decreases from scratch between the source and the final target.

For example, Obsidian Field is in play, Legacy had Fortitude (-1 damage taken) and Lead from the Front, and Tempest has Localized Hurricane (+1 damage taken) in play.  Baron Blade tries to deal Tempest 1 damage.  That would be 3 damage (+1 from the Hurricane, +1 from Obsidian Field), but Legacy redirects that damage to himself.  So we recalculate from scratch as 1 (base damage) + 1 (Nemesis with Baron Blade) - 1 (Fortitude) + 1 (Obsidian Field) = 2 damage taken.  The fact that Tempest would have taken 3 damage is irrelevant.*

- Well, mostly irrelevant.  There are a few redirects that only trigger for certain amounts of damage.  But once the redirect has been triggered, it doesn't matter if the final calculated damage is different from the amount that triggered the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

A quick break down of what would happen using his base power of deal himself 1 cold or 1 fire damage.

1. Use the power to deal 1 fire damage to himself
2. Damage is increased by 1 twice so he takes 3 damage.
3. Isothermic Transducer triggers causing him to be able to do 2 damage to 1 target
4. That 2 damage by 1 twice so the target takes 5 damge

Short and simple each time damage is assigned it is increased by the card so in the end he will do 2 more damage twice to the target than he was originally going to do to himself